# 404 error for tomcat 6 for spring application

Tags: java, spring, tomcat6, web.xml

My app is deployed properly but getting 404 error.
Unable to find what is happening.
In this **deployed** means pointing my webapp folder to location in computer.

URL used :

> **localhost:8080/studentspringmvc/**

**web.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <web-app version="2.5" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

 <display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

 <context-param>
     <param-name>contextConfigLocations</param-name>
     <param-value>classpath*:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
 </context-param>


 <servlet>
     <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Now I have added studentspringmvc.xml in conf/Catalina/localhost folder as

**studentspringmvc.xml**

```
<Context path="/studentspringmvc"
  docBase="/home/shoaib/Documents/myprograms/studentspringmvc/src/main/webapp" 
 reloadable="true" 
/>
```

Unable to find why atleast index.html is not loading.
[image]
[image]

Comment: did you checked tomcat logs? what does it say?

Comment: No error deployed success. May be I am firing wrong url or mention wrong url pattern. I have uploaded new image which shows studentspringmvc true.

Comment: where exactly is this applicationContext.xml files located?

Comment: WEB-INF.....no issue with that. It has found applicationContext.xml files and all.

Comment: are you deploying on tomcat inside eclipse? if yes then your Context should contain source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:PROJECTNAME"

Comment: Its intellij and I am not running from IDE. I am running from console.

Comment: please show me your mvc-dispatcher and applicationContext.xml file as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dispatcher servlet is mapped to `/`. This means that **every** URL is mapped to this servlet (index.html included). To make sure static files are still served, you need to enable the default servlet handler as explained in [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-default-servlet-handler):

```
<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
```

Comment: But adding this line my control is not coming to Controller.