# Unable to map request to Controller in Spring MVC 3

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Firstly, I was unable to get the index page but I resolved that issue using [404 error for tomcat 6 for spring application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21760201/404-error-for-tomcat-6-for-spring-application)

After I get index page and when I click on link I am unable to map the request to my Controller.

**studentspringmvc.xml**

```
<Context path="/studentspringmvc"
  docBase="/home/shoaib/Documents/myprograms/studentspringmvc/src/main/webapp" 
  reloadable="true" 
  debug="9" />
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <web-app version="2.5" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocations</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath*:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

**StudentDetailsController.java**

```
package com.semanticbits.studentspringapp.controller;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;


@Controller
@RequestMapping("/studentDetails")
public class StudentDetailsController {

   private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(StudentDetailsController.class);

   public StudentDetailsController() {
      System.out.println("In Student Constructor");
   }

   @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
   public String showForm(ModelMap map){
    logger.info("In service method");
    System.out.println("In Student Details");
    return "studentdetails";
   }
}
```

**mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.semanticbits.studentspringapp.*"/>
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>


<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

**index.jsp**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
   <a href="/studentDetails">Click here</a>
</body>
</html>
```

When I click on this link it should get map to StudentDetailsController showForm method displaying another studentdetails.jsp but I am getting 404.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most importantly, you're missing

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

in your servlet context, which discovers `@Controller` annotated beans and their `@RequestMapping` annotated methods, among other things.

Without it, your controller beans stay in the context, not doing much. The `DispatcherServlet` doesn't register them.

Then, when you specify a leading `/` in

```
<a href="/studentDetails">Click here</a>
```

the browser makes the request relative to your host address. So if your host IP is like

```
127.0.0.1
```

then the request will be made to

```
127.0.0.1/studentDetails
```

But you seem to have a context path

```
<Context path="/studentspringmvc"
```

So you need to change it to

```
<a href="/studentspringmvc/studentDetails">Click here</a>
```

or better yet, [make it dynamic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5850336/what-does-this-expression-language-pagecontext-request-contextpath-exactly-do)

```
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/studentDetails">Click here</a>
```